# How to fix python console error in pycharm?

Tags: python, pycharm, xml-rpc

> Exception in XML-RPC listener loop (java.net.SocketException: Socket closed).

When I run PyCharm from bash , I get this error..As result: I cant't use python-console in pycharm Anybody know how to fix it ?

OS: ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score -1):

Hi I had the same problem as you. I solved the problem by making the line `127.0.0.1 localhost` as the first line in /etc/hosts. The reason python console does not run is that python console tries to connect to localhost:pycharm-port, but localhost was resolved to the IPv6 addess of `::1`, and the connection is refused.